# Is there a way to spread one image across a collapsible div and its parent div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

In this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/17929/), I have a button with an image in the background. If you click the button, a collapsed column springs out from the bottom.

What I'm looking to do is have that same background image dynamically re-size to fit the *entire* un-collapsed div once it's un-collapsed. Now, I understand that I could do a call like

```
$(this).addClass('imageUpdate');
```

when I want dynamically change the CSS for the header/button div, but this isn't exactly what I'm looking to do; I want the image to resize but to also map itself across the entire expanded column (and the header that it drops down from).

Is there any way that I can get around doing this? Or, as I suspect, can I not have an image span across multiple divs? If this is the case, what alternative would you recommend in order to achieve my goal? Thanks!

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-md-3" id="left-accordion">
  <!-- first set of buttons -->
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="button" data-toggle="collapse"  data-target="#baselayer">CLICK ME<br/>
      <span style="font-size:1.25em;color:#fff;" class="glyphicon"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse" id="baselayer">

      <div class="well selections base-buttons" id="softbutton" role="button">Bulbasaur<br/>
        <div class="selected">

        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="well selections base-buttons" id="medbutton" role="button">Charmander<br/>
        <div class="selected">

        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="well selections base-buttons" id="firmbutton" role="button">Squirtle<br/>
        <div class="selected">

        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.panel-default > .panel-heading {
    color: #fff;
    background-image: url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f7/English_Pok%C3%A9mon_logo.svg/2000px-English_Pok%C3%A9mon_logo.svg.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: 110%;
    border: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need any JavaScript, but move the background to the conatining `<div class="panel-default">`. Then you remove the background of the elements above and you're good.

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/wo7bj00q/)

CSS:

```
.panel-default > .panel-heading {
    color: red;
    background: transparent;
}
.panel-default .well{
    background: transparent;
}
.panel-default {
    background-image: url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f7/English_Pok%C3%A9mon_logo.svg/2000px-English_Pok%C3%A9mon_logo.svg.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: 110%;
    border: none;
}
```

Once you're done, copy the image to your own server for production use, instead of referencing to the one on Wikimedia.

Answer (score 0):

> Or, as I suspect, can I not have an image span across multiple divs

You can have your image as large as you want.
You just have to tell it, how large it should be, by changing the style.width and style.height attributes. (or background-size in your case) 
This is what i would do by JS.

But you want to do it automatically - so I would attach the background-Image to you bigger container .panel-default

But then, the buttons are in front of it, so you would have to change the background-color etc of them ...